# Can't use ini_set because session is active

Tags: php, session, ini-set

How can I fix this?

> Warning: ini_set() [function.ini-set]: A session is active. You cannot change the session module's ini settings at this time in C:\xampp\htdocs****************.php on line 3

I already tried using `session_destroy();` but I still get the error.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried changing the parameters beforehand?

Comment: @Gumbo ini_set('session.cookie_httponly', true);

Comment: Well, change it before starting the session.

Comment: have you done a phpinfo() to see if your config has session.auto_start set on?

Comment: I have the same sporadic random error with my custom session provider. I have no idea what it could be.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

use `session_start();` after `ini_set` or **@** sign before `ini_set`: `@ini_set`

Answer (score 2):

if you server is configured to auto start sessions, you can try also:

```
php_flag session.auto_start 0
```

in your .htaccess file