# Cannot modify header information error when trying to redirect page

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap

I'm following [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ubI-UjqHU18&index=35&list=PLA7F9875BD031DC16) video tutorial and have become stumped on the part where the login page redirects the user to `home.php` from `index.php`. When the user clicks login the credentials are checked and when the head function is called this error pops up:

> "Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by
>   (output started at
>   /home/urbanas8/public_html/register/index.php:19299) in
>   /home/urbanas8/public_html/register/inc/header.inc.php on line 22"

Line 19299 is just

```
<?php require_once("./inc/header.inc.php");?>
```

and line 22 is

```
header("location: home.php");
```

here is the `header.inc.php` file:

```
<?php 
            session_start();
            ini_set('display_errors', 1);
            error_reporting(E_ALL);
            require_once( "./inc/connect.inc.php" );


            if(isset($_POST['login'])){                 
                $user_login = strip_tags(@$_POST['user_login']);
                $password_login = strip_tags(@$_POST['login_password']);

                $password_login = md5($password_login);

                $sql = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM users WHERE email='$user_login' AND password='$password_login' LIMIT 1");
                $userCount = mysql_num_rows($sql);
                if($userCount == 1){
                    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
                        $id = $row["id"];
                    }
                    //echo("pass");
                    //$_SESSION['user_login'] = $user_login;
                    header("location: home.php");
                    exit();
                }else {
                    echo("/invalid username/password");
                    exit();
                }
            }
    ?>
        <div id="top-bar">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                        <ul id="top-info">
                            <li>Phone: 703-518-4325</li>
                            <li>Email: <a href="mailto:info@urbanare.com">info@urbanare.com</a></li>
                        </ul>
                        <ul class="nav pull-right" id="top-buttons" style="line-height:10px !important;">
                            <li class="dropdown">
                                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><i class="fa fa-sign-in"></i>Log in<strong class="caret"></strong></a></a>
                                <ul id="login-dp" class="dropdown-menu" style="padding: 15px;">
                                    <form action="" method="POST" accept-charset="UTF-8">
                                        email: <input id="user_username" style="margin-bottom: 15px;" type="text" name="user_login" size="30" />
                                        password: <input id="user_password" style="margin-bottom: 15px;" type="password" name="login_password" size="30" />
                                        <input id="user_remember_me" style="float: left; margin-right: 10px;" type="checkbox" name="remember" value="1" />
                                        <label class="string optional" for="user_remember_me"> Remember me</label>
                                        <input class="btn btn-primary" style="clear: left; width: 100%; height: 32px; font-size: 13px;" type="submit" name="login" value="Sign In" />
                                    </form>
                                </ul>
                            </li>

                            <li class="divider"></li>

                            <li><a href="../register"><i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o"></i> Register</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="sticky-wrapper"><div id="nav-section">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                        <a href="http://comingsoon.safepropserv.com/landing/index.html" class="nav-logo"><img src="./files/logo_transparent.png" alt="UrbanaRE Logo"></a>

                        <!-- BEGIN SEARCH -->
                        <div id="sb-search" class="sb-search">
                            <form>
                                <input class="sb-search-input" placeholder="Search..." type="text" value="" name="search" id="search">
                                <input class="sb-search-submit" type="submit" value="">
                                <i class="fa fa-search sb-icon-search"></i>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                        <!-- END SEARCH -->

                        <!-- BEGIN MAIN MENU -->
                        <nav class="navbar">
                            <button id="nav-mobile-btn"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></button>

                            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                                <li class="dropdown">
                                    <a href="./files/UrbanaRE -- Property Info.html" data-toggle="dropdown" data-hover="dropdown">Home<b class="caret"></b></a>
                                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                        <li><a href="http://comingsoon.safepropserv.com/landing/index.html">Home Search</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="http://comingsoon.safepropserv.com/landing/index-slider.html">Home Slider</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="http://comingsoon.safepropserv.com/landing/index-grid.html">Home Grid</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="http://comingsoon.safepropserv.com/landing/index-map.html">Home Map</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>

                                <li class="dropdown">
                                    <a href="./files/UrbanaRE -- Property Info.html" data-toggle="dropdown" data-hover="dropdown">Properties<b class="caret"></b></a>
                                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                        <li><a href="http://comingsoon.safepropserv.com/landing/properties-detail.html">Properties Detail</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="http://comingsoon.safepropserv.com/landing/properties-list.html">Properties List</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="http://comingsoon.safepropserv.com/landing/properties-grid.html">Properties Grid</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="http://comingsoon.safepropserv.com/landing/properties-grid2.html">Properties Grid 2</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>

                                <li class="dropdown">
                                    <a class="dropdown" href="./files/UrbanaRE -- Property Info.html" data-toggle="dropdown" data-hover="dropdown">Pages<b class="caret"></b></a>
                                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                        <li><a href="http://comingsoon.safepropserv.com/landing/about.html">About Us</a></li>
                                        <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                                            <a href="./filse/UrbanaRE -- Property Info.html">Agency</a>
                                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                                <li><a href="http://comingsoon.safepropserv.com/landing/agency-detail.html">Agency Detail</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="http://comingsoon.safepropserv.com/landing/agency-listing.html">Agency Listing</a></li>
                                            </ul>
                                        </li>
                                        <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                                            <a href="./files/UrbanaRE -- Property Info.html">Agent</a>
                                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                                <li><a href="http://comingsoon.safepropserv.com/landing/agent-detail.html">Agent Detail</a></li>
                                                <li><a href="http://comingsoon.safepropserv.com/landing/agent-listing.html">Agent Listing</a></li>
                                            </ul>
                                        </li>
                                        <li><a href="http://comingsoon.safepropserv.com/landing/pricing-tables.html">Pricing Tables</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="http://comingsoon.safepropserv.com/landing/login.html">Login</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="http://comingsoon.safepropserv.com/landing/register.html">Register</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="http://comingsoon.safepropserv.com/landing/faq.html">FAQ</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="http://comingsoon.safepropserv.com/landing/404.html">404</a></li>

                                        <li class="divider"></li>
                                        <li><a tabindex="-1" href="./files/UrbanaRE -- Property Info.html"> Separated link </a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>

                                <li class="dropdown">
                                    <a href="./files/UrbanaRE -- Property Info.html" data-toggle="dropdown" data-hover="dropdown">Blog<b class="caret"></b></a>
                                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                        <li><a href="http://comingsoon.safepropserv.com/landing/blog-detail.html">Blog Detail</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="http://comingsoon.safepropserv.com/landing/blog-listing1.html">Blog Listing 1</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="http://comingsoon.safepropserv.com/landing/blog-listing2.html">Blog Listing 2</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="http://comingsoon.safepropserv.com/landing/blog-listing3.html">Blog Listing 3</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="http://comingsoon.safepropserv.com/landing/blog-listing4.html">Blog Listing 4</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>

                                <li><a href="http://comingsoon.safepropserv.com/landing/contacts.html">Contacts</a></li>
                            </ul>

                        </nav>
                        <!-- END MAIN MENU -->

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div></div>

    <!-- END HEADER -->
```

Comment: <?php require_once("./inc/header.inc.php");?>  did you try with two dots... I am not confirmed about this but i think it would be like <?php require_once("../inc/header.inc.php");?>

Comment: try to use `mysqli` instead of `mysql` to prevent hijacking...

Comment: kindly remove unwanted spaces from your code (insed the `<?php  ... ?>`) and try again.

Comment: it is referencing the right directory. When I add another dot the page doesnt even load.

Comment: just put `ob_start()` at very first line of `header.inc.php`

Comment: ^Already tried that.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reference - What does this error mean in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php)

Comment: dupe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11384416/cant-use-ini-set-because-session-is-active you can't change ini settings after starting the session.

Comment: maybe utf-8/bom issue

Comment: none of these solutions are working help plz

Answer (score 1):

According to the error message you shared.

The output is started at "index.php:19299" (before including header.inc.php)

if you dont have any space (before ob_start(); at first line of your index.php file.

```
<?php ob_start();
```

Comment: are you sure that index.php is your first running file? if so, read this answer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/how-to-fix-headers-already-sent-error-in-php

Answer (score 1):

You should try comment below lines:

```
  //       ini_set('display_errors', 1);
     //       error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

Or you should check there should nothing echo in header. because this error mostly occurs when something is echoing before the header redirect.

Comment: Ok it is showing blank because you have disable showing error. Please check in this file require_once( "./inc/connect.inc.php" ); if something is being echo there. if it is then comment that echo and try.

Answer (score 0):

Removed session_start(); from the header and put it at the top of the index file... 3 hours later.